# how does CF(Carry flag) get set according to the computation t = a-b where a and b are unsigned integers

Tags: bit-manipulation, x86-64, instructions, instruction-set

I'm new to x64-64, just a question on how does CF get set? I was reading a textbook which says:

***CF: Carry flag is used when most recent operation generated a carry out of the most significant bit. Used to detect overflow for unsigned operations.***

I have two questions:

Q1-suppose we used one of the add instructions to perform the equivalent of the C assignment t = a+b, where variables a, b, and t are integers (only 3 bits for simplicity), so for `011`(a) + `101`(b) = `1000` = `000`, since we have a carry out bit `1` in the fourth digit, so CF flag will be set to 1, is my understanding correct?

Q2-if my understanding in Q1 is true, and suppose we used one of the sub instructions to perform the equivalent of the C assignment t = a-b, where a, b, and t are **unsigned** integers, since  a, b are unsigned, we can't actually do `a+(-b)`, and I don't get how we can make `011`(a) - `101`(b)  carry out of the most significant bit?

Comment: 5 - 3 wouldn't carry so that's not a good example.

Comment: @harold could you give me a good example?

Comment: 3 - 5 would work, in general subtracting a larger number from a smaller one

Comment: @harold I have modified my question to use `011` - `101` = 3 - 5, still don't know how can we have a fouth overflow bit so that CF flag can be set?

Comment: related: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt covers Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags which are generally meaningful for unsigned vs. signed respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carry flag is often called "borrow" when performing a subtraction.  After a subtraction, it set if a 1 had to be borrowed from the next bit (or would have been borrowed if you used the grade-school subtraction method).  The borrow flag is like a -1 in that bit position:

```
  011     -1 211
- 101  ->  - 101
-----      -----
           B 110
```

You can get the same result by adding a zero to the arguments, and then the carry or borrow will be the high bit of the result:

```
 0011 - 0101 = 0011 + (-0101) = 0011 + 1011 = 1110
```

Comment: Note that on some ISAs, the carry flag has the opposite meaning for subtraction.  But on x86, yes, it's a simple borrow output as if the subtract were done this way, *not* as if adding the 2's complement inverse or something.